# Find the largest size string in a list python?

Tags: python, list

I have a list as follows:

```
input1 = ['XS','S', 'M', 'L', 'XL', 'XXL', 'XXXL']

input2 = ['XS', 'S', 'M', 'L', 'XL', 'XS', 'S']

input3 = ['XS', 'S', 'M', 'L', 'S]

input4 = ['XS', 'S', 'M', 'L', 'XS', 'L']
```

etc.

As you see the list elements will change every time. I want to know how to find the largest element each time.

the standard list is this :

```
['XS','S', 'M', 'L', 'XL', 'XXL', 'XXXL']
```

This is what I have tried:

```
lst1 = {k:v for k, v in enumerate(['XS', 'S', 'M', 'L','XL','XXL', 'XXXL'])}

lst2 = ['XS', 'S', 'M', 'L', 'XL', 'XS', 'S']

tem = []

for i in lst2:
  for k,v in list(lst1.items()):
    if i == v:
      tem.append(k)


print(lst1[max(tem)])
```

But this is very complicated I guess. It should be much easier!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just *reverse* the dictionary and use the [get](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) function as key to [max](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max):

```
lst1 = {v: k for k, v in enumerate(['XS', 'S', 'M', 'L','XL','XXL', 'XXXL']) }
lst2 = ['XS', 'S', 'M', 'L', 'XL', 'XS', 'S']

result = max(lst2, key=lst1.get)
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
XL
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to overcomplicate stuff with dictionaries when simple string search would be enough.

```
lst1 = ['XS', 'S', 'M', 'L','XL','XXL', 'XXXL']
lst2 = ['XS', 'S', 'M', 'L', 'XL', 'XS', 'S']

result = next(x for x in lst1[::-1] if x in lst2)
```

If you don't want to reverse the list, just create on opposite order